# Boost event log doesn't display events properly

Tags: c++, boost, event-viewer

I have some issues with boost event logger. When I try log to the event log using `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` I get no severity in the event viewer. (everything is displayed as information, but not as warning, error etc.) The boost library is dynamically linked to the application. I use 1.57 version of the library.

Here is screenshot. Every event should be displayed as warning but it doesn't.[image: Event log view]

Here's my init code:

```
try
{
    boost::log::add_common_attributes(); //edit
    boost::shared_ptr<sink_t> sink(new sink_t
        (
        log_name = "test_app",
        log_source = "test_app"
        ));

    sink->set_formatter
        (
        expr::format("[%1%] - %2%")
        % expr::attr<ptime>("TimeStamp")
        % expr::smessage
        );

    sinks::event_log::custom_event_type_mapping<MessageSeverity> mapping("Severity");
    mapping[MessageSeverity::error] = sinks::event_log::error;
    mapping[MessageSeverity::warning] = sinks::event_log::warning;
    mapping[MessageSeverity::info] = sinks::event_log::info;

    sink->locked_backend()->set_event_type_mapper(mapping);
    core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << e.what();
}
```

And here's how I log events

```
void Logger::log(MessageSeverity severity, const std::string & msg)
{
    switch (severity)
    {
    case MessageSeverity::info:
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << msg;
        break;

    case MessageSeverity::warning:
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << msg;
        break;

    case MessageSeverity::error:
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << msg;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` emits log records with severity level having type `boost::log::trivial::severity_level`. That is the type of attribute values you should be expecting in the `custom_event_type_mapping`, not the `MessageSeverity`. Since the type does not match, the library is unable to extract severity level from log records and uses `sinks::event_log::info` as the mapped event type as a fallback.

You should either use `boost::log::trivial::severity_level` in the event type mapper or use a [logger](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.severity_level_logger) specialized for `MessageSeverity`.

```
boost::log::sources::severity_logger< MessageSeverity > lg;
BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, MessageSeverity::warning) << "Hello, warning.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to register your log level to the severity attribute ?

This what I would use :

```
 #include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
 ...
 BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity, "Severity", MessageSeverity);
```

Also your logging calls are still using boost severity level.

Update it like the following (/!\ Untested) :

```
void Logger::log(MessageSeverity severity, const std::string & msg)
{
     switch (severity)
     {
      case MessageSeverity::info:
      case MessageSeverity::warning:
      case MessageSeverity::error:
         BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(severity) << msg;
      default:
       break;
     }
}
```

Comment: I do use `boost::log::add_common_attributes();`. I tried macro version but it didn't work. I forgot to mention that :)

Comment: Okay, can you show how you are calling the logging functions ? (Edit your question to do so)

Comment: Ok, done :) Should I use another macro instead of `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` ?

Comment: What's the point of defining your own severity to switch case like that ?